# Is there a basic How to document for the Userbean in the extlib

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have looked at the XPageExt.nsf and search the web looking for a straight forward How To document on implementing the UserBean. Has someone a video or blog that explains how?

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.eknori.de/2012-05-08/access-userbean-from-java/

Answer (score 0):

Also there is some info on the userBean in the "XPages Extension Library" book (page 509-511), which includes a chart of properties you can access - like commonName and accessLevel.